# How to pass a List<Object[]> to a Thymeleaf email template HashMap model without using ModelAndView

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to bind a List of Object arrays to a Thymeleaf view. But I am failing. How do I correctly bind the list?

I have a custom Hibernate Query in Spring Boot:

```
List<Object[]> l = tr.findAccessSummary();
```

The result is a list l that I then place into a model Map:

```
Map model = new HashMap();
model.put("list",l);
```

The model is sent to the Thymeleaf view as follows:

```
<tr th:each="l,iterationStatus : ${list}">
    <td th:text="${l.unitNum}"></td>
    <td th:text="${l.event}"></td>
</tr>
```

When I call this in Thymeleaf side, I see the below:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'unitNum' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.Object[]' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

I expect that the List to be set in the model and to be readable in the Thymeleaf template. However, this is not the case.

Below is the output:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'unitNum' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.Object[]' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

Comment: I don't think your variables are what you think they are. In this loop: `th:each="l,iterationStatus : ${list}"` `l` is an `Object[]` (because ${list}` is a `List<Object[]>`. An `Object[]` doesn't have a property `unitNum` (which is the error you are getting), why do you think it does?

Comment: I agree. My variables are not what I think they are - hence I am getting the errors. Just to clarify, The custom Hibernate query returns a result that is not based on the Entity. The query looks like this:  

@Query("select t.unitNum,count(t.event) from TapTap t group by t.unitNum order by count(t.event) desc")

So I get 2 columns instead of the complete columns I would get if it returned the full columns of the Entity. Could this be where I am going wrong?

Object[] does not have the property unitNum because I am not returning an Entity? Or I have not type casted?

Comment: So what happens if you use `<td th:text="${l[0]}" /><td th:text="${l[1]}" />` instead of `<td th:text="${l.unitNum}" /><td th:text="${l.event}" />`?

Comment: Thanks, I will test your suggestion shortly. I should know better because in a different implementation for text only email, I used the below.

for ( Object[] rr :l) {
      String a = (String)rr[0];
      Long b = (Long)rr[1];
      body = body.concat(a + "   " + b + "\n");
}

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Thank you.